# How do I sleep for long periods with PyQt threads?

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, sleep

I have a number of certain objects which need to run a specific function at specific ever-changing intervals, again and again, until they decide they are done.

For example, one object may need to wait 30 seconds, run, wait 60 seconds, run, wait 10 seconds, run... You get the point, and this could be going on for 30-120 different objects, running the exact same kind of function.

I was thinking that simply having a function that sleeps for the exact interval would solve my problem, but, correct me if I'm wrong, I remembered that thread pools *can only run a certain number of threads at any given time* (12 for me). **How do I get around this limit?**

```py
class Thing(object):
    def getCurrentPeriod(self):
        return random.randint(5, 30) # Some ever changing period of time

    def refresh(self):
        doThings() # A long running task that is disk and network intensive

    def waitRefresh(self):
        period = self.getCurrentPeriod()
        time.sleep(period) # Wait that period out
        self.refresh()
        return self.needRefresh()
        # Boolean if it needs to restart - Not sure about how to reschedule,  
        # or specifically where to connect the worker emit when it finishes 
        # to make sure this *specific* Thing obj gets it's waitRefresh func called again.

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

    # Add initial objects to pool (other portions of app may add more over time)
    for thing in self.acquireThings():
        worker = Worker(thing.waitRefresh)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
```

Doesn't include the WorkerSignals class nor the QRunnable subclass, [this](https://gist.github.com/Xevion/495bc631b87510977322ad154640f196) example includes what I usually do. The example is tackling the same problem, but in a (most likely) inefficient way.

edit: [New example](https://gist.github.com/Xevion/c15bff14dcb70edd56da4e58b4df4607) with complete working example of how `time.sleep` does not pause the thread and allow others to work. I feel that `async` may be the only implementation, but is there a quick fix so I don't have to alter my entire app?

[Here's what it looks like when you try to sleep more than 12 threads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3TFI.png)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for which you can't use Qt's implementations of timers/sleep/etc?

Comment: First off QThreadPool is for disposable/reusable short term Threads -- for long time and/or continuous Threads you want to use QThread (not sure if there is a limit on these) of course you can also use Multiprocessing but that might be more complex than you need. As for using a Timer with the EventHandler there will be some issues due to how Threads are handled in Python (lookup GIL). If you need it to be precise that is going to extremely difficult however if you just need it to activate and eventually run that should be fine.

Comment: @musicamante I am actually not aware of what Qt implements for sleep functions. I saw `QThread.wait`, but I didn't see anything for `QRunnable` or `QThreadPool`. I'm currently looking into what I can do for `Timer` implementations, but I do like my current `QRunnable` implementation.

Comment: @DennisJensen Not sure how I can contact you, but I'll look into `QThread` after I get my `QTimer` implementation working (or not). I'm staying away from `processEvents` strictly since I've heard that there are a lot of problems with it (and my stuff is starting to get very complicated).

Comment: @Xevion your examples are maybe a bit too abstract to exactly understand what you need. For what we know, you could even try to do the same by using a [QTimeLine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimeline.html) (which is *not* intended for such things, but, it still *might* do what you need). From what I can see, you'll probably need to use a QThread for each object, and implement a system that "walks through" its own timers until it's finished, but it would really help us if you could be more specific about what you're trying to do, so that we could try and find solutions that better fit your needs.

Comment: @musicamante I created another WORKING example of what I'm trying to do, but the full explanation would take way too long and honestly, isn't worth your time (I'm afraid you'd waste it and we'd be no closer to a ultimate solution). https://gist.github.com/Xevion/20e2e0b84850320fa74bedb5a82aa3b3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate solution came when I decided to actually try the `QTimer` class. Perhaps there are more optimized solutions, but this one seems to hit all the checkboxes, even if it's worryingly simple.

```py
import random
import time
import traceback

from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    """
    Represents the signals a Worker can emit.
    """
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    starting = pyqtSignal(int) # ID of thread
    result = pyqtSignal(tuple) # Tuple refresh result, result and ID

class Worker(QRunnable):
    """
    A worker designed to tell when it's starting, when it's finished and the result.
    Designed to work around Thread.refresh().
    """

    def __init__(self, fn, thread_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.id = thread_id
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        """
        Runs a given method, and emits the result with the Worker's coordinated ID.
        """
        try:
            self.signals.starting.emit(self.id) # Thread is now finally ready to work.
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) # Refresh Thread!
            self.signals.result.emit(result) # Thread is finished, emit result tuple.
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done


class Thread(object):
    """
    Basic Rules for a Thread Object:
    Cannot store the next timestamp on the object (it's a database object, I don't believe it's good practice
    to be creating sessions over and over to simply read/write the access time.
    ID and Active are allowed as booleans.
    """
    i = -1

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Thread.nextID()
        self.active = True
        self.refreshes = 0

    def refresh(self) -> tuple:
        """
        'Refreshes' a thread. Waits a specific period, then decides whether Thread object should be deactivated or
        returned from additional refreshes. Chance of deactivation lowers with each refresh.
        :return: The refresh result, a tuple with a boolean and the thread's ID (for identifying it later)
        """

        # Represents my SQL Alchemy Model's refresh() function
        self.refreshes += 1
        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
        if random.random() <= max(0.1, 1.0 - ((self.refreshes + 5) / 10)):
            self.active = False
        return self.active, self.id

    @staticmethod
    def getRefreshTime() -> float:
        """
        Represents the amount of time before a thread should be refreshed.
        Should NOT be used to determine whether the thread is still active or not.

        :return: The time period that should be waited.
        """

        return random.uniform(10, 300)

    @staticmethod
    def nextID() -> int:
        """
        Returns integer thread IDs in sequence to remove possibility of duplicate IDs.
        :return: Integer Thread ID
        """
        Thread.i += 1
        return Thread.i

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Thread(id={self.id} active={self.active})'


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """
    GUI containing a Label, Button and ListWidget showing all the active sleeping/working threads.
    Manages a threadpool, a number of background singleshot timers, etc.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Widgets Setup
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.list = QListWidget()
        self.l = QLabel("Total Active: 0")
        self.button = QPushButton("Refresh List")
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.refreshList)
        self.button.setDisabled(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.l)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)
        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.show()

        # Periodically add threads to the pool.
        self.poolTimer = QTimer()
        self.poolTimer.setInterval(5_000)
        self.poolTimer.timeout.connect(self.addThreads)

        # Threading Setup
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        self.active, self.threads = {}, {}
        # Add a number of threads to start with.
        for _ in range(random.randint(5, 16)):
            self.setupThread(Thread())
        self.poolTimer.start()

    def refreshList(self):
        """
        Refreshes the ListWidget in the GUI with all the active/sleeping/working threads.
        """
        self.list.clear()
        bold = QFont()
        bold.setBold(True)

        active = 0
        for thread in self.threads.values():
            item = QListWidgetItem(
                f'Thread {thread.id}/{thread.refreshes}')
            # Bold a thread if it's working
            if self.active[thread.id]:
                active += 1
                item.setFont(bold)
            self.list.addItem(item)
        self.l.setText(f'Total Active: {active}/{len(self.threads)}')

    def refreshResult(self, result) -> None:
        """
        When a thread is finished, the result determines it's next course of action, which is either
        to return to the pool again, or delete itself.

        :param result: A tuple containing the result (bool) and the connected Thread ID.
        """
        self.active[result[1]] = False
        if result[0]:
            print(f'Restarting Thread {result[1]}')
            self.setupThread(self.threads[result[1]]) # Add by ID, which would normally be a database GET
        else:
            print(f'Thread {result[1]} shutting down.')
            del self.active[result[1]]
            del self.threads[result[1]]
        self.refreshList()

    def updateActivity(self, thread_id) -> None:
        """
        Connected to the starting signal, helps signal when a thread is actually being refreshed.

        :param thread_id: The Thread ID
        """
        print(f'Thread {thread_id} is now active/working.')
        self.active[thread_id] = True

    def refresh(self, thread):
        """
        Adds a new worker to the threadpool to be refreshed.
        Can't be considered a real start to the thread.refresh function, as the pool has a max of 12 workers at any time.
        The 'starting' signal can tell us when a specific thread is actually being refreshed, and is represented
        as a Bold element in the list.

        :param thread: A thread instance.
        """
        print(f'Adding Thread {thread.id} to the pool.')
        worker = Worker(thread.refresh, thread_id=thread.id)
        worker.signals.result.connect(self.refreshResult)
        worker.signals.starting.connect(self.updateActivity)
        self.threadpool.start(worker)
        # self.active[thread.id] = True
        self.refreshList()

    def setupThread(self, thread) -> None:
        """
        Adds a new timer designated to start a specific thread.
        :param thread: A thread instance.
        """
        self.active[thread.id] = False
        self.threads[thread.id] = thread
        t = QTimer()
        period = thread.getRefreshTime()
        t.singleShot(period * 1000, partial(self.refresh, thread=thread))
        print(f'Thread {thread.id} will start in {period} seconds.')
        self.refreshList()

    def addThreads(self):
        """
        Adds a number of threads to the pool. Called automatically every couple seconds.
        """

        add = max(0, 30 + random.randint(-5, 5) - len(self.threads))
        if add > 0:
            print(f'Adding {add} thread{"s" if add > 1 else ""}.')
            for _ in range(add):
                self.setupThread(Thread())

app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

When a Thread is requested, a Timer is created and `singleShot` is fired on an extra function that will add it to the threadpool. This threadpool can handle up to 12 refreshing continious 'refreshing' threads, and signals allow the GUI to update the moment a change is found.

Thousands of 'Thread' objects can be waiting and it seems `singleShot` is capable of adding them to the pool exactly when they need to be.

Signals help differentiate when a thread is `sleeping`, `working` and `active` (but `inactive` Thread objects are immediately removed).

The only caveats I can think of with this program is:

1) Can a QThread implementation beat it?

2) What happens to the `QTimer` once it's `singleshot` function has executed and fired? Will they be properly GC'd, or can thousands build up in the background consuming resources?